# mysql найти ссылки на изображения в поле типа text

Tags: mysql, изображения, url

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как построить выражение, чтобы найти ссылки на изображения http:://*.jpg|png|gif в поле типа text, думаю, скорее всего с помощью like, но хотелось бы знать мнение профи, чтобы запрос был полегче и не создавал огромную нагрузку.

Comment: С помощью `like`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно попробовать вот так (условие LIKE возможно надо подкорректировать),

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] LIKE '%http://%.jpg%' OR [column] LIKE '%http://%.png%' OR [column] LIKE '%http://%.gif%'
```

или с regexp

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] REGEXP 'http://.*\.(jpg|png|gif)'
```

Что в Вашем случае будет лучше, надо проверять.